# why I cannot create histograms with calcHist in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, histogram

this is my code for calculation of histogram:

```
Mat hist;
int histSize = 4000;
float range[] = { 0, 4000 } ;
int channels[] = {0};
const float* histRange = { range };
bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;
for(int i = 0; i < sz;i++){
    id = orders.at<int>(i);
    int from = activities[id].frame_from;
    int to = activities[id].frame_to;
    Mat labelsForHist = labels(Range(from,to),Range(0,1));     
    calcHist(&labelsForHist,1,channels,Mat(),hist,1,&histSize,&histRange,uniform,accumulate);  

}
```

but I am getting this error: `error: (-210) in function calcHist`
in for loop I am getting values from certain ranges of the `labels` array and put it into `labelsForHist` to calculate its histogram.
any idea why i get this error?

Comment: complete error msg please

Comment: `/opt/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 1219
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/fnegin/opt/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:1219: error: (-210)  in function calcHist`

Comment: CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, ""); looks like int Mat's are not supported. why don't you look at the code ?

Comment: it works with this Mat: temp = Mat::zeros(1000,1,CV_32f);

Comment: it is float, so i need to change my values to float ?

Comment: i did this and it works now: `Mat labelsForHistFloat;
        labelsForHist.convertTo(labelsForHistFloat, CV_32F);`